# How can I replace in a string every character + space with another character

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working in python 3.5.  I need to convert any space that is to the right of any other character to a "|".

For example:

```
string1 = "Sub Total             34       658.43     100.00%       19.37"
```

needs to become:

```
"Sub|Total|            34|      658.43|    100.00%|      19.37| "
```

Thanks in advance for any help you could give me.

Comment: `19.37| "`: the space in the end isn't logical / doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical choice: regular expressions:

```
import re

string1 = "Sub Total             34       658.43     100.00%       19.37"

print(re.sub(r"(?<=[^ ])( |$)","|",string1))
```

lookbehind for a non-space to replace space by a `|` only if after a non-space, or at the end of the string.

That gives:

```
Sub|Total|            34|      658.43|    100.00%|      19.37|
```

if you really need the space at the end, just add it afterwards.